# Python 2.7 reading and writing "éèàçê" from utf-8 file

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I made this script which removes every trailing whitespace characters and replace all bad french characters by the right ones.

Removing the trailing whitespace characters works but not the part about replacing the french characters.

The file to read/write are encoded in UTF-8 so I added the utf-8 declaration above my script but in the end every bad characters (like \u00e9) are being replaced by litte square.

Any idea why?

script :

```
# --*-- encoding: utf-8 --*--

import fileinput
import sys

CRLF = "\r\n"

ACCENT_AIGU = "\\u00e9"
ACCENT_GRAVE = "\\u00e8"
C_CEDILLE = "\\u00e7"
A_ACCENTUE = "\\u00e0"
E_CIRCONFLEXE = "\\u00ea"

CURRENT_ENCODING = "utf-8"
#Getting filepath
print "Veuillez entrer le chemin du fichier (utiliser des \\ ou /, c'est pareil) :"
path = str(raw_input())
path.replace("\\", "/")

#removing trailing whitespace characters
for line in fileinput.FileInput(path, inplace=1):
    if line != CRLF:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line
        print >>sys.stderr, line
    else:
        print CRLF
        print >>sys.stderr, CRLF
fileinput.close()

#Replacing bad wharacters
for line in fileinput.FileInput(path, inplace=1):
        line = line.decode(CURRENT_ENCODING)
        line = line.replace(ACCENT_AIGU, "é")
        line = line.replace(ACCENT_GRAVE, "è")
        line = line.replace(A_ACCENTUE, "à")
        line = line.replace(E_CIRCONFLEXE, "ê")
        line = line.replace(C_CEDILLE, "ç")
        line.encode(CURRENT_ENCODING)
        sys.stdout.write(line) #avoid CRLF added by print
        print >>sys.stderr, line
fileinput.close()
```

## EDIT

the input file contains this type of text :

```
 * Cette m\u00e9thode permet d'appeller le service du module de tourn\u00e9e
 * <code>rechercherTechnicien</code> et retourne la liste repr\u00e9sentant le num\u00e9ro 
 * de la tourn\u00e9e ainsi que le nom et le pr\u00e9nom du technicien et la dur\u00e9e 
 * th\u00e9orique por se rendre au point d'intervention.
 *
```

## EDIT2

Final code if someone is interested, the first part replaces the badly encoded caracters, the second part removes all right trailing whitespaces caracters.

```
# --*-- encoding: iso-8859-1 --*--

import fileinput
import re

CRLF = "\r\n"

print "Veuillez entrer le chemin du fichier (utiliser des \\ ou /, c'est pareil) :"
path = str(raw_input())
path = path.replace("\\", "/")

def unicodize(seg):
    if re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', seg):
        return seg.decode('unicode-escape')
    return seg.decode('utf-8')

print "Replacing caracter badly encoded"
with open(path,"r") as f:
    content = f.read()
replaced = (unicodize(seg) for seg in re.split(r'(\\u[0-9a-f]{4})',content))

with open(path, "w") as o:
    o.write(''.join(replaced).encode("utf-8"))

print "Removing trailing whitespaces caracters"
for line in fileinput.FileInput(path, inplace=1):
    if line != CRLF:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line
    else:
        print CRLF
fileinput.close()

print "Done!"
```

Comment: You mean you have squares in the output file or in your script ?

Comment: The definition of `ACCENT_AIGU` etc. doesn't seem right. `"\\u00e9"` represents the string `\u00e9` *not* the unicode character with code-point `00e9`. If you want to unicode character you should write `u"\u00e9"`.

Comment: @pypat : In the output file, Bakuriu, i'm guessing that is what I want (using "\\u00e9" see my update

Comment: try to use the method replace("words or charters to be removed","") instead of strip

Comment: @EngHamoud : I am using replace("words or charters to be removed","new char")

Comment: I wish people would stop thinking that adding an encoding declaration in their code files somehow magically makes "unicode work". Lots and lots of wrong answers on SO are at least partly to blame.

Comment: As a sidenote, french use more non-ASCII characters that just this subset. Here are _some_ examples in common words: [aigüe](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aig%C3%BCe)(orthographe réformée) [aiguë](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aigu%C3%AB) (othographe traditionelle), [hôtel](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%B4tel), ... You should use the support for the unicode database integrated with Python (`unicodedata`) to perform the mapping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not so quick, and mostly dirty, but...

```
with open("enc.txt","r") as f:
    content = f.read()

import re

def unicodize(seg):
    if re.match(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', seg):
        return seg.decode('unicode-escape')

    return seg.decode('utf-8')

replaced = (unicodize(seg) for seg in re.split(r'(\\u[0-9a-f]{4})',content))

print(''.join(replaced))
```

Given that input file (mixing unicode escaped sequences and properly encoded utf-8 text):

```
 * Cette m\u00e9thode permet d'appeller le service du module de
 * tourn\u00e9e
 * <code>rechercherTechnicien</code> et retourne la liste
 * repr\u00e9sentant le num\u00e9ro 
 * de la tourn\u00e9e ainsi que le nom et le pr\u00e9nom du technicien
 * et la dur\u00e9e 
 * th\u00e9orique por se rendre au point d'intervention.
 * 
 * S'il le désire le technicien peut dormir à l'hôtel
```

Produce that result:

```
 * Cette méthode permet d'appeller le service du module de
 * tournée
 * <code>rechercherTechnicien</code> et retourne la liste
 * représentant le numéro 
 * de la tournée ainsi que le nom et le prénom du technicien
 * et la durée 
 * théorique por se rendre au point d'intervention.
 * 
 * S'il le désire le technicien peut dormir à l'hôtel
```

Answer (score 5):

You are looking for `s.decode('unicode_escape')`:

```
>>> s = r"""
...  * Cette m\u00e9thode permet d'appeller le service du module de tourn\u00e9e
...  * <code>rechercherTechnicien</code> et retourne la liste repr\u00e9sentant le num\u00e9ro
...  * de la tourn\u00e9e ainsi que le nom et le pr\u00e9nom du technicien et la dur\u00e9e
...  * th\u00e9orique por se rendre au point d'intervention.
...  *
... """
>>> print(s.decode('unicode_escape'))

 * Cette méthode permet d'appeller le service du module de tournée
 * <code>rechercherTechnicien</code> et retourne la liste représentant le numéro
 * de la tournée ainsi que le nom et le prénom du technicien et la durée
 * théorique por se rendre au point d'intervention.
 *
```

And don't forget to `encode` your string before writing it to a file (e.g. as UTF-8):

```
writable_s = s.decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This is quite nice, however it will tranform all good characters (example : "é") to stuff like : Ã© (those are old file so you can find some good and bad characters)

Comment: @sliders_alpha If I understand it well, your file _is_ encoded as UTF-8, but somehow _some_ characters where replaced by their "unicode escape code"? Or is it a "mix" between UTF-8 and some other encoding (Latin1 ?)

Comment: @sliders_alpha oh, so your file is a mixture of escaped and non-escaped character, that's bad. Unfortunatelly, those two encodings don't play together well, and I couldn't come up with any simple solution…

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Yes, that seems to be right. The problem is that after decoding utf-8 you already have a `unicode` object and you can't decode escape-sequences with `unicode_escape`…

Comment: As an heuristic, `regex`-based approach ?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I have no idea how to handle it right, but, well, yeah, manually replacing all backslash-escapes probably is the way to go…

Comment: @Sylvain Leroux : well I don't know much in encoding, it is possible to have multiple encoding in the same file? (in properties I can see that all my files are encoded in UTF-8)

But yes I have some "\u00e9" ans some "é" in the code.

Comment: is there a way to find the "Ã©" in the code? line.find("Ã©") do not really works

Comment: @sliders_alpha `Ã©` is simply `é` not properly decoded from utf-8.

Comment: @sliders_alpha A text file _must_ be encoded using _one_ given encoding. By mistake -- you could find files, as this is your case, where some parts use one encoding and some parts an other. This is the case for example if the file was edited using utf-8 and later using latin1 -- without re-encoding the rest of the document. Since such a document is not compliant with any encoding scheme, this is a nightmare to process.

Comment: erf, Well then I think it's what is happening, I'm going to use decode('unicode_escape').encode('utf-8'), because I have 95% of "\\u00xx", I'll change the other one by hand then re-encode the whole file as utf-8 for futur devellopers.

Comment: @sliders_alpha Don't do anything by hand if a computer could do it :D See my answer for a working solution (I hope)...

Comment: @sliders_alpha If you don't have backslashes followed by special characters (e.g. `é`), I think the following will work: `s.decode("utf8").encode("unicode-escape").replace("\\\\u", "\\u").decode("unicode-escape")`

Answer (score 1):

To read a file encoded in utf-8 that has non-ascii characters in it and that literally has `\`, `u`, `0`, `0`, `e`, `9` character sequences that you also want to decode:

```
import codecs
import re

repl = lambda m: m.group().encode('ascii', 'strict').decode('unicode-escape')
with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = re.sub(r'\\u[0-9a-f]{4}', repl, file.read())
```

Note: normally, non-ascii characters and Unicode escapes (`\uxxxx`) should not be mixed in a single file. Use one or another but not both simultaneously.

> The file to read/write are encoded in UTF-8 so I added the utf-8 declaration above my script

The utf-8 declaration in your Python source affects only character encoding of your Python source e.g., it allows to use non-ascii characters in bytestring and unicode literals. It *has no effect* on character encoding of the files that you read.

> but in the end every bad characters (like \u00e9) are being replaced by litte square.

"litte square" might be an artifact of printing to console. Try this in a console to see whether squares are present:

```
>>> s = "\u00e9" # 6 bytes in a bytestring
>>> len(s)
6
>>> u = u"\u00e9" # unicode escape in a Unicode string
>>> len(u)
1
>>> print s
\u00e9
>>> print u
é
>>> b = "é" # non-ascii char in a bytestring
>>> len(b) # note: it is 2 bytes 
2
>>> ub = u"é"  # non-ascii char in a Unicode string
>>> len(ub)
1
>>> print b
é
>>> print ub
é
>>> se = u.encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace') # non-ascii chars are escaped
>>> len(se)
4
>>> (s.decode('unicode-escape') == u == b.decode('utf-8') == ub == 
     se.decode('unicode-escape') == unichr(0xe9))
True
```