# Problems converting an external .txt file into a List in Python?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, encoding, io

I have a `.txt` file with some strings like this:

```
word_1
word_2
word_3
....
word_n
word_n-1
```

I would like to read them and place them into list, in order to do something like this:

```
my_words = set(['word_1',...,'word_n-1'])
```

This is what I tried:

```
with open('/path/of/the/.txt') as f:
   lis = set([int(line.split()[0]) for line in f])
   print lis
```

But I get this error:

```
    lis = set([int(line.split()[0]) for line in f])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xc3\xa9l'
```

What would be a better way to do this and how can I deal with the encoding of this extarnal `.txt` file?.

Comment: that words are in byte format?

Comment: you cant covert a "word" into an int, unless your words are numeric "1", "34", etc.

Comment: Remove the `int` call and it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. @GLHF the words are just in a txt file(utf-8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lis = set(line.strip() for line in f)
    print lis
```

The result is:

```
set(['word_3', 'word_2', 'word_1', 'word_21', 'word_123'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!. This works any idea of how to fix encoding issues?. For example when I run this I get some encoding problems:`'manifest\xc3\xb3', 'ellas', 'estuvo', 'agreg\xc3\xb3'`. They're spanish words.

Comment: Probably you need to look at encoding. For example something like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17060810/python-2-7-reading-and-writing-%C3%A9%C3%A8%C3%A0%C3%A7%C3%AA-from-utf-8-file).

Comment: That is not an encoding problem that is the repr output printing it will look like `manifestó`

Comment: So the encoding of the words is still the same?. This is just happening by tha fact that I am printing the results on the pycharm terminal?.

Comment: @johndoe Maybe its new problem. New question could be more appropriate. If you decide to create new one, linking to the file of interest or its example would be useful.